# Just starting one instance of Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

How do I start just one instance of Visual Studio 2008?

For example, if I assign a favorite shortcut for [Outlook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Outlook), and press this key, every time it takes me back to the one and only instance of Outlook.

How do I get this to work with Visual Studio 2008? I don't want it to start another instance whenever I press the shortcut key, but go back to the one and only instance?

Comment: [OneOnly](http://www.softlist.net/program/oneonly-software.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that the command line
switch "/Edit" for devenv.exe will open in a running
instance (and start a new one if there isn't one). Specify a
harmless text file, some file you would open anyway or some
other text file (for example, a [to-do list](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/to-do_list#Noun)).

Thus, in the [shortcut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_shortcut#Microsoft_Windows)'s "Target" field, for example:

```
"D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /edit S:\temp2\someHarmLessTextFile.txt
```

Comment: Gold Man!
Exactly what I wanted, I using MS keyboard and I added the edit switch for that key- goes back to opened instance, but I can still open new instances via the "default route" to the app - Great!

/Regards
Christer

Comment: I'm trying to get this to work with a file that has a designer. In this case, it's a **wiq** file. `/Edit` shows the xml. Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you for this, I found way to many posts about this that didn't do what I was looking for. +1